# why my application is not able find activity to handle an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am using switch case for optionmenu.But i getting some error.i have checked  logcat also it says

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.app1.ABOUT }
```

a small piece of code is give below that i have written in my java class.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutus:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.app1.ABOUT");
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.preferences:
        Intent s = new Intent("com.app1.PREFS");
        startActivity(s);

        break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        break;

    }
    return false;
}
```

and the code of android manifest is given below.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.app1.Aboutus"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ABOUT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

am i refereeing the manifest in correct way from my java class ?

Comment: add `com.app1.PREFS` and `com.app1.ABOUT` name as activity to manifest file and change intent constructor with `(context , class)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this your manifest..

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.app1.Aboutus"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

      <activity android:name="com.app1.ABOUT"/>         

      <activity android:name="com.app1.PREFS"/>
```

In java

```
case R.id.aboutus:
    Intent i = new Intent(Aboutus.this, ABOUT.class);
    startActivity(i);
    break;

case R.id.preferences:
    Intent s = new Intent(Aboutus.this, PREFS.class);
    startActivity(s);
```

Comment: it is ok to have have another way of solving this issue but i would like to know where i am wrong.what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // I  can modify like this
     Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.ths, Activity2.class);
     startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The package name you are using inside intent & the name in you manifest are different. So, change the activity names inside manifest to:

```
<activity android:name="com.app1.ABOUT"/>         
<activity android:name="com.app1.PREFS"/>
```

because these are the names u are using inside intent.

```
Intent s = new Intent("com.app1.PREFS");
```

So, should be the same name both in manifest & while using in intent.